# Can the grid system be used within a bootstrap modal popup?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i created the bootstrap modal popup and display correctly, before i created my modal popup in jquery UI,

but i moved to bootstrap modal popup because of responsiveness

question is : do we need to use grid system (i.e - row and columns) inside the bootstrap modal popup context for responsive ?

what i did now is , just copy/paste my old html contenxt for jquery modal popup to bootstrap modal popup.

Comment: Yes I've used grids and responsive tables within modals and they are responsive. However the modals come in 3 sizes so the responsive behavior also applies to the modal size.

Comment: ah, so what i used without gridsystem, will not working for responsive :)

Comment: Yes without using grid within the modal it won't be responsive. I would highly recommend you try using responsive tables. It also used a grid system by setting the column width that adds up to 12. Check out this project I've been working on at http://triplewww.com/cm/separation/separation.html I think you want this type of behavior in the modals.

Comment: Then I'll post the answer you can vote me up! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes without using grid within the modal it won't be responsive. I would highly recommend you try using responsive tables. It also used a grid system by setting the column width that adds up to 12. Check out this project I've been working on at triplewww.com/cm/separation/separation.html I think you want this type of behavior in the modals.  You will want to reference this in bootstrap [responsive tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) that can be used in modals.